# Can you implement only the transactional tracking with Google Analytics enhanced ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

Can you implement solely the transactional enhanced eCommerce without the product impressions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) indicates to me that you can use just pieces of it.  It says:

> There are multiple types of ecommerce data you can send using analytics.js: impression data, product data, promotion data, and action data.

It doesn't say you *have to* send any of them, it says you *can*.  Furthermore it says:

> #### Combining Impressions and Actions
>
> In cases where you have both product impressions and an action, it is possible to combine and measure this in a single hit.

This further implies that sending impression data is optional.  It only combines the data if it has it to do so.

Comment: Stephen's interpretation of the documentation is correct, most features are optional. I know this because I have worked on multiple custom GA implementations on E-commerce sites in the last few years.